# how can i get record in another table (SQL)

Tags: sql, database

i have 2 tables

table1 :

```
----------------------------------------
| id | request_id | user_id | mitra_id |
----------------------------------------
```

table2:

```
-------------------------
| mitra_id | mitra_name |
-------------------------
```

how can i get mitra_name using mitra_id in table1?

Comment: Use Join b/w two tables.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON(t1.ID = t2.ID)` .

Comment: use JOIN in order to do that

Comment: This question has been asked to death. Please learn to search for answers as it is one of the most important skills you can learn!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tab1.*
     , tab2.mitra_name
FROM table1 tab1
INNER JOIN table2 tab2
  ON tab2.mitra_id = tab1.mitra_id;
```

To learn some superbasic SQL:

[W3Schools intro to SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

[W3Schools INNER JOIN lesson](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Do it by a simple inner join:

```
SELECT t2.mitra_name 
FROM table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
ON t1.mitra_id = t2.mitra_id
```